# Internet Explorer flash.net.URLStream close() Method Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, firefox, internet-explorer-8, mozilla

Is anyone else aware of the fact that Internet Explorer (at least version 8) keeps downloading a file even if the close() method is called on an URLStream instance?

Heck, it even keeps downloading if you close the tab displaying the site which called the load()/close() methods on an URLStream instance.

**Does anyone know of a solution to overcome this problem?**

*More details:
My preloader is loading a dozen of files and immediately closing the download streams with the purpose of checking each resource's file size. In Mozilla Firefox all goes well, exactly as expected, but Internet Explorer keeps downloading the resource even if the stream has been interrupted by the action script close() method.*

Comment: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-20 *(or https://web.archive.org/web/20090502234723/http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-20 if that link is down)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that IE doesn't always do that, so there can't be a solution to this question.